# How to choose the right number of dimension in UMAP?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I wanna try to use UMAP for my high-dimensional dataset as a preprocessing step (not for data visualization) in order to decrease the number of features, but how can I choose (if there is a method) the right number of dimensions in which to map the original data? For example, in PCA you can select the number of Factors that explain a fixed % of variances.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to do this comparable to the explicit measure given by PCA. As a rule of thumb, however, you will get significantly diminishing returns for an embedding dimension larger than the `n_neighbors` value. With that in mind, and since you actually have a downstream task, it makes the most sense to build a pipeline to the downstream task evaluation and look at cross validation over the number of UMAP dimensions.

Comment: What is the downside of trying to directly measure the explained variance of a UMAP-ed dataset versus the original dataset (e.g. via https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#explained-variance-score). Something to do with assumptions of linearity perhaps? Would this be totally uninformative in some circumstances or at least a good-enough measure if your modeling pipeline is not ideally suited to finding the best embedding dimension (e.g. our use case is unsupervised)?